# AWS and .Net Remoting

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, remoting, .net-remoting

We are looking into migrating some of our application layers to AWS, and keeping the rest on-premise in a hyprid approach for a period of time.

There will be a VPN connection between the AWS hosting center and the on-premise data center.

My question is, if I have a .Net remoting service on-premise, can I call it from AWS or not?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the answer is Yes, it can be done. We have tried it out and the performance is quite relevant to the size of the data you are sending over the VPN between AWS and the on-premise service.